# Is MAX(rowversion) optimized for the table?

Tags: sql-server

When trying `MAX(rv)` for the table--the `rv rowversion` is defined there--I have noticed that the operation is very fast even for big tables. Is there an index implemented implicitly for the `rowversion` column? Or is the `MAX()` function optimized for the rowversion value? In other words, is the maximum value for the rowersion of the table stored elsewhere?

It is SQL Server 2014 if it matters.

Comment: What does the query plan say?

Comment: The correct answer would be `why do you care`? [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is only used as a way to implement optimistic concurrency. It's not a normal value, `MAX(rv)` has no real meaning and can't really be used to find modified rows. That's what change tracking is for. The value comes from a database-wide counter, with heavy caching optimisations, which can result in jumps and gaps. It's quite possible that the latest value used is stored in the table's metadata (I haven't checked).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: If I remember the last maximum value related to the source tables, then I know when to mirror the table from the sources again, and I can restrict mirroring only to the newer rows. In the case when only few of say 6 million rows changes, and they be mirrored separately, it makes sense. The key is whether I can rely on getting the `MAX(rv)` from each table really quickly.

Comment: You *don't*. That's the point. `rowversion` is only meant for optimistic concurrency. What you want is [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Besides, `rowversion` won't show deleted records, which change tracking will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't appear there is any special treatment for `rowversion` columns.  This small demo confirms the entire index is scanned to find the `MAX` value:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RvTest
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    rv rowversion,

    CONSTRAINT PK_RvTest PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.RvTest
    (Id)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [number]
FROM master.dbo.spt_values v1
WHERE 
    v1.[number] IS NOT NULL;
GO

SELECT MAX(rv) FROM dbo.RvTest;
```

[image: Screenshot of index scan in Plan Explorer]

[Interactive db<>fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8a15a97c03f711bb197115ad9ff75fe)

This makes sense when you consider that the `rowversion` is unique across the whole database, rather than a specific table:

> Each database has a counter that is incremented for each insert or update operation that is performed on a table that contains a rowversion column within the database. This counter is the database rowversion.

It doesn't look like SQL Server stores table-specific metadata about `rowversion`s.

If you need that check to be very fast, there's nothing stopping you from indexing that column yourself:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_rv ON dbo.RvTest (rv DESC);
```

Which results in a single row being read for that `MAX` query:

[image: Screenshot of single row NC index scan in Plan Explorer]

---

As a side note, as [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/480/panagiotis-kanavos) has mentioned in the comments, this is *usually* used for optimistic concurrency checks - to tell if a specific row has changed since the last time it was read.  The way you're using it is still valid (keeping the last maximum, and checking the current max to see if any data in the table has changed), although the built-in [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) feature might be attractive to you as an alternative.

Comment: Then rowversion column is probably indexed (it is already fast). I am mirroring partial information from the 3rd party database (solution based on Navision), and I am not allowed to modify their database to set the change tracking on. I am aware of the DELETE problem. Anyway, this is (rowversion) specific for the solution, for the source tables, in my case.

Comment: @pepr Ah, understood about the restrictions.  Well if they are already indexed, then you should be good to go!